# Dutch Number & 2 Decimal Place Validation Power APP

Tags: regex, powerapps

A UK number looks like this 233.25 .

For a Dutch Number, it looks like this in the Power APP 233,25.

This works for the Power App in the UK but not in Holland, due to the comma for the decimal separator. How can I change this to get it to work? I have tried an OR statement but it does not work . ( ( TextInput.Text,"\d+(.\d{0,2})?") ) - REGEX

If(IsMatch( TextInput.Text,"\d+(.\d{0,2})?"),   //justify whether meet the format
Submit(Form1),   //submit the form if the result is true
Nodify("wrong format",NotificationType.Warning))              //display Notification if the result is false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to format it yourself. Regardless of what the user inputs.

```
Left(Value(TextInput.Text),Len(Value(TextInput.Text))-2) & "," & Right(Value(TextInput.Text),2) & "."
```

[image]

Comment: That does not format the number correctly for any of the 2 situations with these numbers

Comment: Users enter X, you want them formatted to look like Y. Can you give examples for what X and Y would be? I believe there is also a language parameter for the Value() and Text() functions. The Netherlands language code would be "nl" or "nl-NL".